# How to execute a child kernel 256 times concurrently in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm a newbie at CUDA programming, but I need use it in a complex project. I really need some help.

My question is if I want to execute a child kernel 256 times concurrently what can I do with Dynamic Parallelism?

I read an NVIDIA [blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-api-principles/) , and it says:

> By default, grids launched within a thread block are executed
>   sequentially: the next grid starts executing only after the previous
>   one has finished. This happens even if grids are launched by different
>   threads within the block.

So, my idea is setting block size(1,1) and grid size(256,1) for the parent kernel and I can launch the child kernel concurrently with 256 threads in different blocks. Will it be very inefficient? What's a better solution?

Comment: It is not quite clear, why you want to launch them concurrently.
As you describe it, it could very well be sufficient to just launch one block with 256 threads...

Comment: Launching single threads in a block is very inefficient and should be avoided if possible. You should launch in multiples of the warp size (32 for current hardware) if at all possible.

Comment: @DanielBauer Sorry, it's my first time to ask a question in this forum. Let me be more specific.I have a data matrix which size is (512,1024) . I need do an operation on every row pair, and I want this operation to be executed 256 times concurrently to save time. This operation contains calculating FFT(or convolution), getting the index of maximum value in the FFT result and shift the data in its original location.(Actually, this process is called range alignment in Inverse Synthetic Aperture Radar imaging).

Comment: Try making a kernel that is using as many resources as you can at a time, then run this kernel in one big grid. CUDA should automatically process as many blocks concurrently as it can. Normally, you don't have to do something about concurrency if you're running only one task repeatedly. If you will be calculating different tasks, where it is unclear wheather one needs data from the other one, you need to think more about this stuff

Answer (score 2):

That quote continues with

> Often, however, more concurrency is desired; as with host-side kernel launches, we can use CUDA streams to achieve this. All streams created on the device are non-blocking; that is, they do not support implicit synchronization with the **default** NULL stream. Therefore, what follows is the only way to create a stream in device code.

```
cudaStream_t s;
cudaStreamCreateWithFlags(&s, cudaStreamNonBlocking);
```

Then using a different (device-side)stream per CUDA thread should make them run independently instead of the default one.

Additionally, you can coalesce multiple launches into one big launch using some reduction algorithm between parent threads in a parent block. Incrementing total number of threads of child kernel and their mapping from thread id to problem space. This should overcome the performance issue of small kernels combined with the *maximum number of concurrent kernel executions per device*(4 to 128 depending on Cuda Compute Capability) supported by hardware.

Comment: The maximum number of current grids is between 4-128. This varies with compute capability. See https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications "Maximum number of resident grids per device". 32 is the maximum number of communication channels starting with GK110.